# How to use 2 datasets on SSRS to compare and show the result

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008 to build the report

Functionality:

I have created report which is having 2 datasets

```
1) dslocation
2) prevdslocation

There are few fields like say:

    1) locationId
    2) locationName
    3) mmpremium
    4) sspremium
```

In my report I need to show the result as below :

```
Locationname        mmpremium(dslocation) - mmpremium (prevdslocation)

SANDY                1000 - 2000
RANSY                2000 - 3000
```

I want to do this in the report level instead of SQL to return as single dataset.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You could have many tables sat alongside each other as long as you could be certain that the tables would be sorted identically. This would give a physical join in appearance. Can I ask why you would not wan to join in SQL to return a single dataset?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, do this kind of thing in SQL it makes like much easier...

However, you can use LOOKUP to achieve this if it's a simple 'join' between the two datasets.

Create table based on your first dataset (dsLocation) then add an extra column and set the expression to something like this...

```
=Lookup(Fields!LocationID.Value, Fields!LocationID.Value, Fields!mmPremium.Value, "prevDsLocation")
```

This will look at the locationid for the row, try to find a match in LocationID in prevDsLocation and if it finds a match it will return mmPremium from prevDsLocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Following are the tables and data used for report creation-
create table dslocation
(
locationId int
 ,    locationName varchar(20)
  ,   mmpremium int
  , sspremium int
)
INSERT INTO dslocation
VALues (1, 'SANDY', 1000,'')
,(2, 'RANSY', 2000,'')

create table prevdslocation
(
plocationId int
 ,    plocationName varchar(20)
  ,   pmmpremium int
  , psspremium int
)

INSERT INTO prevdslocation
VALues (1, 'SANDY', 2000,'')
,(2, 'RANSY', 3000,'')

Then add a column and write following expression in placeholder-
=Fields!mmpremium.Value-join(LookupSet(Fields!locationId.Value,Fields!plocationId.Value,Fields!pmmpremium.Value,"prevdslocation"),",")

Following is the screenshot of the solution -
[![enter image description here][1]][1]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdKML.jpg
```